# OpenCV Brisk not detecting any keypoints

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction, imagedownload

I have an image that I'd like to detect in a larger image (i.e. see if a similar version is present). Template matching is not accurate enough, as the items can be rooted and scaled, so Brisk seems a hopeful approach:

However, when I try to create descriptors, I get no return:

Here is my example image:

[image]

```
BRISK = cv2.BRISK_create()
keypoints1, descriptors1 = BRISK.detectAndCompute(img, None)
```

returns

```
 ([], None)
```

Any suggestions how I can get better results? Why does Brisk not detect any features? Changing threshold to 0 and adding octaves doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is way too small to find any meaningful descriptors. Unless you use a larger sized image, following is a solution that can be used:

```
img = cv2.imread("/path/to/image/so_brisk.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Gray
w, h = gray.shape
scale_factor = 3
gray = cv2.resize(gray, (h*scale_factor, w*scale_factor), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

BRISK = cv2.BRISK_create()
keypoints1, descriptors1 = BRISK.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
```

Comment: ok that seems to work. thanks. When I get matches from the BFMatcher, how can I best determine which card is the best match? Is Brisk suitable for this at all?

Comment: To be honest I have not used BRISK for any project, I have used SIFT and that has worked pretty well. Since BRISK is an alternative to SIFT, my hunch feeling is that it's at least as good as SIFT. Using it to find the best match is going to be tricky, you may have to pick, say, top 5 or 10 descriptors (distance-wise and sorted by distance min to max) and do a least squares to find the closest match among the candidate images. But that code is certainly going to be highly inefficient when images are large and perhaps even not very accurate.

Comment: looks like a neural network is probably more appropriate for a classification task like this

Comment: Yes indeed. I was going to suggest that but didn't because that's going to be quite a bit of work. I do use it quite extensively in my app. Btw., the solution I posted solves the problem that you posed as a question :D

Comment: here we go. but have a little follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039211/image-classification-reaches-99-accuracy-on-training-but-when-done-outside-of