# Image classification reaches 99% accuracy on training, but when making predictions suddenly all is wrong

Tags: python, tf.keras, image-classification

I have written the code in this gist that classifies poker images with a neural network. Training reaches 99% accuracy but when reloading the trained model, all is wrong.
https://gist.github.com/dickreuter/ca20c40e3f5dbf45504933e0da359b4d

The following steps are taken:

- Downloads 52 Poker cards from a rest api
- uses Keras ImageDataGenerator to create augmented data (100 rotated and twisted version of each card). This is saved in a training, validation and test folder.
- The cards are loaded with Keras' ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory and trained on a neural network. After a few minutes it reaches 99% accuracy.
- The model is then saved (model, weights and classification dictionary).
- The code then reloads the model and makes a few classifications on some cards. They are all wrong.

Any suggestions what could be going wrong are greatly appreciated.

I'm aware this is quite an open ended question, but anybody who would be able to help pinpoint the issue, that would be fantastic.

As you can see, training, validation and testing all yields 99% accuracy.

```
Epoch 10/20
53/53 [==============================] - 17s 325ms/step - loss: 0.0239 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.0497 - val_accuracy: 0.9937
Epoch 00010: early stopping
52/52 [==============================] - 4s 66ms/step - loss: 0.0057 - accuracy: 0.9985
Test loss: 0.005703429691493511
Test accuracy: 0.9984615445137024
```

But when I then take a sample out of the test set and try to predict it, they are all incorrect:

```
test_cards/AS/AS_0_1045.png
KS
Correct: False
test_cards/5C/5C_0_1032.png
5S
Correct: False
test_cards/KS/KS_0_1033.png
KC
Correct: False
```

Comment: Are the tests done on out-of-sample cards? If yes, then my guess is the model is overfitting during training.

Comment: no, it's in sample. As you can see there are various steps taken to avoid overfitting, such as early stopping, regularization and data augmentation.

Comment: When you train the model, you said training accuracy reaches 99%, what's the test accuracy alongside it? Just on a side note, 100 images per class is way too low a number. I would recommend at least 5000 per class. For better accuracy generally you should be in the ballpark of 100K+.

Comment: test accuracy is 99% as well. The pictures are very small and it's nowhere near as complicated as differentiating cats and dogs. So it seems as if it's some kind of coding error rather than a conceptual problem.

Comment: How many images do you have in training folder?

Comment: one image of each category is downloaded and then 100 augmented versions are created of each category. After training it reaches 99.9%. Takeing any images that are used from the training and making a prediction almost always fails.

Comment: While using generators you use `rescale`, but when loading the image manually you don't rescale it. That's the problem.

Comment: interestingly when di do: `model.evaluate(test_generator, steps=52)` I get 99%, but  I try `model.predict_generator(test_generator, nb_samples)` it's all in random order